# Is a directory Error in Django deployment

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am building a website with django for months. So now i thought its time to test it with some friend. While deploying it to a Ubuntu 14.4 64bit LTS ( Same as development environment ) i found a strange error.

Called

```
OSError at /accounts/edit/
[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/var/www/media/'
```

I also tried with different path `BASE_PATH + "/media"` Which was ok for my development.

I am running the default django development server (As its a test!)

It will be really awesome if someone correct me and teach me what's wrong here.

Thanks.

Edit: (Traceback)

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://playbox.asia:8000/accounts/edit/

Django Version: 1.6.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'easy_pjax',
 'bootstrap3',
 'djangoratings',
 'taggit',
 'imagekit',
 'playbox',
 'accounts',
 'musics',
 'playlist')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/root/playbox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-        packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/root/playbox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-        packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/root/playbox/accounts/views.py" in edit
  189.                 os.remove(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + profile.avatar.name)

Exception Type: OSError at /accounts/edit/
Exception Value: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/var/www/media/'
```

Comment: could you share the traceback generated?

Comment: Question edited. Traceback added @DhirajThakur

Comment: I think `settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + profile.avatar.name` evaluates to the directory `/var/www/media/`. You should check the variable profile.avatar.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `profile.avatar.name` evaluates to a **blank string**

So No file is being provided to `os.remove` to remove and It **can't remove a directory** and **raises OSError** : See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove

You can rectify this error by **applying a conditional**, which is what to be followed:

```
if profile.avatar.name:
 os.remove(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + profile.avatar.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me for another reason. Answering here in case it is not the situation above.

I had a file named "admin" in my static folder, which matched the directory "admin" where Django's admin app stores its static files.

When running `collectstatic` it would conflict between those two. I had to remove my "admin" file (or rename it) so it didn't clash.

In general, make sure your files don't clash with any static file provided by other app.